# Retrieving DNA sequences from a fasta file using IDs

Tags: shell, awk

I have two files, one contains only IDs while the other is a fasta file containing sequences (including IDs ofcourse), all IDs in file_1 has their sequences in file_2. I need to retrieve the full sequence of each ID from file_2, the retrieved sequence should contain the full seq record (should contain the identifier followed by sequence)

```
file_1.txt
BGIBMGA000006
BGIBMGA005922
BGIBMGA005925
BGIBMGA008023
BGIBMGA005928
BGIBMGA009805

file_2.fasta
>BGIBMGA000006 BGIBMGA000006-PA B6DXA9 Osiris 18
MARIIVLLSIVAFASATYPASKLVKNIYNECLSQYSVECVKPRTLQWMSSVANDDEIKIT
EDLSIVKTGTVEDDESADPRLAKDPAYEMFDKVDKFLQSHTLRVKVPEEITKSAASEYVP
RSLLTDLPSELDMPLDGEDEAEVVEGRKKKIKLPKPLRIKSKHGFIKKVILPFLLGLKFK
>BGIBMGA000010 BGIBMGA000010-PA B6DXB0 Osiris 9; Uncharacterized 
MKCLVVLMVIGVAWAMPAAEQDSDPNILGSVLGVVKECVDGDVTLCLKEKALRYVETLRS
KREITLVDGVTLDSKGSPRSARALEPLPEEPKAREAQVESRLVDGVADFLENYVVQFKLP
>BGIBMGA000012 BGIBMGA000012-PA H9IRZ2 Uncharacterized protein 
MLKYIALLALTASVQCNPLKENSISENLVGVISECIERDTSLCIKEKALKFTERLAFSKD
MNIFDGMSLVNIGSARSARSYEPLAEDPKARELQLDERIADNMGDFLENHVIQLRLSEPE
AESRSLDDEARGKKKKKLKQLLPLLLLLKLKLAALIPLFLGIIAFVAVKAVFLGKIAFAM
>BGIBMGA000022 BGIBMGA000022-PA H9IRZ2 Uncharacterized protein 
MLKYIALLALTASVQCNPLKENSISENLVGVISECIERDTSLCIKEKALKFTERLAFSKD
MNIFDGMSLVNIGSARSARSYEPLAEDPKARELQLDERIADNMGDFLENHVIQLRLSEPE
AESRSLDDEARGKKKKKLKQLLPLLLLLKLKLAALIPLFLGIIAFVAVKAVFLGKIAFAM
```

Sample output for ID BGIBMGA005922 should be

```
>BGIBMGA000022 BGIBMGA000022-PA H9IRZ2 Uncharacterized protein 
MLKYIALLALTASVQCNPLKENSISENLVGVISECIERDTSLCIKEKALKFTERLAFSKD
MNIFDGMSLVNIGSARSARSYEPLAEDPKARELQLDERIADNMGDFLENHVIQLRLSEPE
AESRSLDDEARGKKKKKLKQLLPLLLLLKLKLAALIPLFLGIIAFVAVKAVFLGKIAFAM
```

My Awk usage is still very basic. I tried a couple of times but no good result. any help please

Comment: why not write simple program using your fav. language?

Comment: [ROSALIND](http://rosalind.info/) is crafted especially for bioinformatics people to learn a programming language (designed for Python).

Comment: Why would your "sample output" be the match for `BGIBMGA005922` instead of `BGIBMGA000022`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### AWK script

Here is a simple AWK script that should do what I think you want (call it, say, `findfasta.awk`):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
BEGIN {
    while ( getline < "-" ) {
        selected[$0] = 1
    }
    RS=">"
}
$1 in selected {
    printf ">%s", $0
}
```

It should be called like this:

```
    cat file1.txt | awk -f findfasta.awk file2.txt
```

It prints every record of the "fasta" file `file2.txt` with an ID that is included in `file1.txt`.  With your given `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` it produces:

```
>BGIBMGA000006 BGIBMGA000006-PA B6DXA9 Osiris 18
MARIIVLLSIVAFASATYPASKLVKNIYNECLSQYSVECVKPRTLQWMSSVANDDEIKIT
EDLSIVKTGTVEDDESADPRLAKDPAYEMFDKVDKFLQSHTLRVKVPEEITKSAASEYVP
RSLLTDLPSELDMPLDGEDEAEVVEGRKKKIKLPKPLRIKSKHGFIKKVILPFLLGLKFK
```

I'm assuming that your "sample output" is what should be given for ID `BGIBMGA000022` and that your ID of `BGIBMGA005922` is a typo.  If this assumption is incorrect, please correct me.

### How it works

This script first reads lines from *stdin* (`"-"`), which is the dump of `file1.txt`.  Hopefully the `file1.txt` will not be too long of a list, because it must be kept in memory.  The array `selected` is an associative array.  Only the key is used, the value could be anything (`1` is used above).  I think it's implemented as some kind of hash table, so checking for inclusion (the `in`) should be fast.  The biggest issue would be the size of `file1.txt` because it must fit in this structure in memory.

The script then proceeds through the input file `file2.txt` (the "fasta" file).  Each record is separated by a `>`.  If the first field of the record is in the `selected` IDs, it will print the whole record along with a replaced `>` (which was removed from parsing).

### Consider more programming

If you are going to be doing bioinformatics things like this often, I suggest learning a more powerful and efficient programming language.  AWK is great for short and simple things and I am a big fan of it, but it does have its limitations.  When you start to deal with larger and larger amounts of data, you need something more efficient and expressive.

There is a great website called [ROSALIND](http://rosalind.info) that is designed especially for bioinformatics people.  It has exercises and tutorials to help you learn Python, and a [problem set](http://rosalind.info/problems/list-view/) to test your skills.